# Retrieving system updates via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, updates

I'm currently working on script which retrieves all updates on system. Why many of scripts after execution do not contain information about other software updates? They only provide with Windows updates. How, e.g., I can retrieve Visual C++ updates, Office and all other software together with Windows updates? Maybe someone can point me to right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this will give you required information? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4197.how-to-list-all-of-the-windows-and-software-updates-applied-to-a-computer.aspx

Comment: hmmm, thank you for solution. But in case anyway If I would like to use "Microsoft Update Client Install History" method to retrieve updates, non of my updates will actually show, because I need to run update check after SCCM OS deployment. But maybe it could work? These updates are not installed by update services but are integrated.

Comment: sorry I don't know and  I have no way of testing it... btw you may also have a look at this article, targeted at SCCM: http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrdogs/archive/2014/08/08/powershell-script-to-list-software-updates-in-a-software-update-group.aspx